# Which javascript loading option would have the most negligible effect on page load time?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous

Let's say I host a javascript file on my server at `www.website.com/javascripts/application.js` that I want 3rd party sites to load up.

On those third party sites, you could just add:

```
<script src="www.website.com/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it would need to evaluate all of the javascript before fully loading the page.

Instead if the third party site had something like

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'www.website.com/javascripts/application.js');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head').appendChild(script);
</script>
```

would this make any difference in the page load time? Would it load the javascript file asynchronously?

What about if the site had

```
<script src="www.website.com/javascripts/dynamic_loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which linked to a script that dynamically built the script tag linking to the `application.js` file as in the example right above this?

Which would be the best option and why? Is there a better way to load third-party javascript that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Your second option will load the script asynchronously and the page can display before the script has loaded.  This can be an advantage if you're optimizing for page display time and no page initialization scripts need to use your script.  This can be a disadvantage (and won't speed the overall page load up) if everything else just has to wait for your script to load before the page can be fully populated.

So, it really depends upon what the script does.  A perfect example of something that can be successfully loaded asynchronously is Google Analytics because it's 100% stand-alone.  Nothing else on the page depends upon it.  When exactly it loads doesn't matter at all in relation to the page display.

An example of something that wouldn't really benefit from loading asychronously is a script that has an integral role in display the initial content or a script that has dependent scripts who have an integral role in the display of the initial content.  Since you can't see the content until they are all loaded anyway, it doesn't really help things to make one of the asynch load.

Dynamic loading (your last option) is most useful when you only want to load modules upon demand (not necessarily when the page loads at all) when they are actually needed (if ever).

Comment: Although if the OP just puts the normal `script` tag at the very bottom of the page, although it may delay "dom ready" sorts of events (and the window `load` event), it doesn't prevent the page from being rendered and responsive. Indeed, this is the whole point of the usual "put scripts at the bottom if you can" advice (such as from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)), and one of many reasons to avoid using "dom ready" sorts of events when you can (you can't always avoid them; libraries frequently have to, for instance, because they don't know where they'll be loaded).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Doesn't the loading of a script at the bottom of the page still delay the responsiveness of the page (though it doesn't delay the rendering)?  After all, you can't have any javascript events until all regular (non-asynch) scripts are loaded.